# Convert text into list using PHP preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this

```
High Resolution: Yes, Very Useful: Yes, Compatible Browsers: IE9, IE10, IE11, Firefox, Safari, Opera, Chrome
```

I want to make this look like

```
<li>High Resolution: Yes</li>
<li>Very USeful: Yes</li>
<li>Compatible Browsers: IE9, IE10, IE11, Firefox, Safari, Opera, Chrome</li>
```

Is there any regex to achieve this, I tried replacing `,` with `</li><li>` but this won't help in the last line.

**UPDATE:** String don't actually have new lines.

Comment: Does your string actually contain new lines? If so, then replace `,` followed by a newline with `</li><li>`

Comment: @MarkBaker no my bad , it' does'nt :)

Comment: If string doesn't have newlines then how to differentiate comma after `Yes` to a comma after `IE9`

Comment: That is what I am trying to resolve :)
Also string has more like `Compatible Browsers` which contain commas.

Comment: If any advanced regex master who knows how can we use `:` to make a regex.

Comment: Why not just split the string at "Compatible Browsers" and then use the replace technique above on the first part and then append the browser part to the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
^(.*?),?$
```

and replace with:

```
<li>$1</li>
```

[Sample](https://regex101.com/r/eJ5pE0/1)

EDIT: Without newlines I'm afraid that a robust solution is impossible, but you can hack something like this ([Sample](https://regex101.com/r/pD8nO6/1)):

```
(\w+\s\w+:[^:]*)(, |$)
```

If you can make some assumptions about input

Comment: he gave you the response + the sample, you can not do a little effort to achieve it ?

Comment: This outputs `
<li>High Resolution: Yes, Very Useful: Yes, Compatible Browsers: IE9, IE10, IE11</li><li></li>`

Answer (score 0):

```
$formatted = "<li>" . str_replace (",\n", "</li><li>", $stringSrc) . "</li>";
```

Comment: I think you missed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082190/convert-text-into-list-using-php-preg-replace#comment48277844_30082190

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using your current method, i.e. replacing `,` with `</li><li>`, then you could do the following to fix the start and end:

```
$string = '<li>' . $string . '</li>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use something other than a comma to separate your list items if you're going to use a comma to *also* separate your sub-list items, eg:

```
$input = "High Resolution: Yes; Very Useful: Yes; Compatible Browsers: IE9, IE10, IE11, Firefox, Safari, Opera, Chrome"
```

Then:

```
echo implode("\n",
    array_map(
        function($a){
            return sprintf('<li>%s</li>', trim($a));
        },
        explode(';', $input)
    )
);
```

which might *look* daunting, but is only technically one line of code, will be marginally more efficient than a regex, and won't drive you insane when your regex goes off the rails for no apparent reason.